# How to create a table of this given code in c?

Tags: c

how can we arrange this in a table so that the address value and name appears in proper rows an columns  ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main() {
int tuna = 20;
printf("Adress \t Name \t Value \n");
printf("%p \t %s \t %d \n",&tuna , "tuna", tuna);

int * pTuna = &tuna;

printf("%p \t %s \t %d \n", pTuna, "tuna", tuna);
printf("%p \t %s \t %p \n", &pTuna, "tuna", pTuna);


_getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the max length of each field?

Comment: its the storage address  of the variable can be random

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your program as follows. Here `%-15` make sure that the data will be printed in 15 character field with left indentation. Of'course the assumption I took here is the data will fit in 15 characters field. You might want to change as per your requirement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main() {
int tuna = 20;
printf("%-15s %-15s %-15s \n","Address","Name","Value");
printf("%-15p %-15s %-15d \n",&tuna , "tuna", tuna);

int * pTuna = &tuna;

printf("%-15p %-15s %-10d \n", pTuna, "tuna", tuna);
printf("%-15p %-15s %-15p \n", &pTuna, "tuna", pTuna);


_getch();
return 0;
}
```

And the output I get:

```
Address         Name            Value           
0xbffff510      tuna            20              
0xbffff510      tuna            20         
0xbffff50c      tuna            0xbffff510
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: yeah but what -15 in (%-15p) basically represents ?

Comment: @MAhmadRana `-15` means the data will be shown in 15 fields with left indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Here,the statement prints the string, but prints at least 15 characters(`"%-15s %-15s %-15s"`). If the string is smaller “whitespace” is added at the end.And thus,it looks 'ordered'.

```
printf("%-15s %-15s %-15s \n","Address","Name","Value");
printf("%-15p %-15s %-15d \n",&tuna , "tuna", tuna);

int * pTuna = &tuna;

printf("%-15p %-15s %-10d \n", pTuna, "tuna", tuna);
printf("%-15p %-15s %-15p \n", &pTuna, "tuna", pTuna);
```

Comment: Like I said above,-15 means that it will print 15 characters,but since for example "tuna" doesn't have 15 characters and has only 4 characters,you should know that it adds empty space characters around it until it has 15 characters length wise.